# actionbar only in some activities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm building an Android app and I'm wondering why some Activities show the Actionbar and some not. The actionbar itself is only showing the app package name. Two activities containing the same xml code have different behaviours. One shows the Actionbar with the app title the other one not.

The launcher activity also shows the actionbar with the app title.

Launcher Activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.LoginActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textpassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.441" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textlogin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.22" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordfield"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:text="Password"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textpassword" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/loginfield"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textlogin" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Login"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordfield"/>
```

One of the two activities with strange behaviour:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/todo_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Additionally I'd like to know how to change the App title in the Acionbar. There doesn't seem to be an option inside the xml defining the title. I think android studio sets this to the project name (which is a working title by me, not the actual "real" app name)? According to the documentation I can build my own app bar (https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up). Would this help?

Comment: post your menifest

Comment: i think it would be better to create your toolbar and add it to all activities... then you can customize app title...

Comment: @FaizMir that was leading me to the strings xml containing the app title. Thanks!

Comment: @MiladBahmanabadi How can I do that? Is it the right documentation I mentioned in my post? (The appbar?)

Comment: yes, thats right i will post an example, hope to help you

Comment: did you try using setTitle(" title") to change the title dynamically

Comment: This is controlled through styles and themes. If your theme has the action bar then it will be there. To set it, just get the activity's supportactionbar and setTitle on it using your localized string. If the actionbar is not there, then check your styles. Also don't touch it, until after onCreate is called to make sure it exists. Lastly, you should consider moving to Toolbar, it is the more modern approach.

Answer (score 0):

To create `Toolbar` and use a custom title in it all you need to do is remember is that `Toolbar` is just a fancy `ViewGroup` so you can add a custom title like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toolbar Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This means that you can style the `TextView` however you would like because it's just a regular `TextView`. So in your activity you can access the title like so:

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

Answer (score 0):

The starange behaviour you are getting might not be that strange.

The `ActionBar` by default show the application name that is set in the `AndroidManifest.xml` as `android:label="@string/app_name"` .

One direct way to use a different title for your `actionbar` in a particular `activity`is to give a lable to that `activity` in the `AndroidManifest.xm` ,as follows:-

```
 <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" android:label="page2"></activity>
```

This might be the reason of the starange behavior.

And  if the some activities are not showing `actionbar` that might be becouse of the `theme` of the activity in the `manifest` file.